# Javascript promise chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, sdk, angular-promise

I'm having quite a hard time understanding how to chain promises.  I'm writing login function for my app, leverating Loopback's Angular SDK.  The objective, upon validating a user's credentials, is to confirm that the user's account is active, then fetch some additional properties including the user's role and set a flag to true if the user has admin privileges.

Here's my code...

```
$scope.login = function (user) {
    User.login(user).$promise.then(
        function (data) {
            $rootScope.activeUser = data;
            $rootScope.user_id = $rootScope.activeUser.user.username;
            console.log('Active User: ', $rootScope.activeUser.user.email);
            console.log('Status: ', $rootScope.activeUser.user.status);
            if ($rootScope.activeUser.user.status === 'Y') {
                $scope.loginError = false;

                function checkAdmin(eid) {
                    Se_user.findById({
                        id: eid
                    }).$promise.then(
                        function (data1) {
                            var user_properties = data1;
                            if (user_properties.role === 'Admin') {
                                $rootScope.isAdmin = true;
                                console.log('isAdminInside: ', $rootScope.isAdmin);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                //$rootScope.isAdmin = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                };

                var isAdmin = checkAdmin($rootScope.user_id);
                console.log('isAdminOutside: ', $rootScope.isAdmin);
                $state.go('home');

            } else {
                $scope.loginError = true;
                $scope.loginErrorMessage = "Your account has been disabled.  Please contact BMT Support for assistance";
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err)
            $scope.loginError = true;
            $scope.loginErrorMessage = "You've entered an invalid User ID or Password.  Please try again.";
        });
};
```

I've been troubleshooting by writing to the console, here's a sample of the output...

```
 Active User:  user@email.com
 Status:  Y
 isAdminOutside:  undefined
 isAdminInside:  true
```

How should I restructure so that the result of checkAdmin is properly returned after a successful login of an active user?

Comment: Promise is asynchronous ! yo ask to write `isAdminOutside` before your promise get resolved so it is undefined at this moment

Comment: What do I need to do so that the isAdminOutside value is set after the promise is resolved?  That's the part I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this part of code :

```js
function checkAdmin(eid) {
  return Se_user.findById({
    id: eid
  }).$promise.then(
    function(data1) {
      var user_properties = data1;
      if (user_properties.role === 'Admin') {
        $rootScope.isAdmin = true;
        console.log('isAdminInside: ', $rootScope.isAdmin);
        return true;
      } else {
        //$rootScope.isAdmin = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
};

var isAdmin = checkAdmin($rootScope.user_id)
  .then(function(val) {
    console.log('isAdminOutside: ', val);
    $state.go('home');
  });
```